# AD group policy update throwing error

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, group-policy, windows-server-2012

So, the entire environment is in AWS. I have 2 VPC's A and B - A has AD in it, and B has multiple domain joined servers. The domain joining and other AD connections work across VPC peering. I can login using domain admin to the VPC B servers (though there's a little lag) successfully. Within the AD, I have added all the users to remote desktop users group, but the other domain users can login to a server only if their domain credentials are added in the local server remote desktop users group. I know this is not the correct way. When I check the rsop, I see that the domain group policy is being inherited, but when I try to update group policy (gpupdate, there comes the error:

Computer policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:

The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the computer name. This could be caused by one of more of the following:
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller.
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller).

User Policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:

The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the user name. This could be caused by one of more of the following:
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller.
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller).

Can someone help me understand what's the issue here.? Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Within the AD, I have added all the users to remote desktop users
>   group, but the other domain users can login to a server only if their
>   domain credentials are added in the local server remote desktop users
>   group. I know this is not the correct way.

That actually is the correct way. Membership in the domain Remote Desktop Users group grants the ability to log onto Domain Controllers via Remote Desktop Services. This domain group does not grant the ability to log on to domain members via Remote Desktop Services.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc756898(v=ws.10)

As for your Group Policy processing problem, what are the domain members using for DNS (in the TCP/IPv4 properties of the NIC)? What is the Domain Controller using for DNS (in the TCP/IPv4 properties of the NIC)?

Comment: All the domain member server NIC's are configured with the private IP address of DC. In DC, nothing is provided as DNS server. But through GPO, we can override the local group membership behaviour, right? Else, if I have like 10+ servers, then in all the servers, I would need to login to confgure this local RD users group, which is difficult. Especially when some user is newly added to AD.

Comment: The DC should use itself for Primary DNS and should use 127.0.0.1 for Secondary DNS. You can use Group Policy Preferences to populate the local Remote Desktop Users group of all of the domain members.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can I do this with group policy preferences? Are you talking about this log on using remote desktop services policy? Please help as I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

We were getting `The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the computer name.` The issue for us was that the clocks were out of sync. And they wouldn't sync with AD because they were out of sync (security issue?). Anyways it was a chicken and the egg.

I forced a clock sync with:

```perl
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"time.google.com" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
```

And `gpupdate` ran successfully. This may help you.

Comment: This does not enforce "a" clock sync, but changes the configuration of the w32tm client entirely - away from the ActiveDirectory. I would not advise to do so, but fix the "real" timesync problem (that may exist here) in the first place.